# Choose to show notification to user in Foreground Swift 5 [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My App always Show notifications in Background and Foreground, bu it must ignore the notification sometimes according to the type.

Two functions do the job on Foreground Notifications:

- userNotificationCenter: It works only on Foregroud Notifications.

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { 
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound]) 
}
```

- application: It works when the user tap the notification

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { 
    ... JOB ... 
}
```

I need to prevent (in foreground) "userNotificationCenter" from showing the visible notification sometimes but always run "application" (the job).

How can I directly call "`application`" without using "`completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])`"

Comment: Your use case for  didReceiveRemoteNotification is wrong. To show or not to show a notification in foreground is just a matter of calling or not calling the completion handler

Comment: I use didReceiveRemoteNotification to do some things after user Tap on visible Notification. There are moments when the User is on Foreground, and it recive a notification that has a specific type which i want to use to not show the Notification to the user. In that moment i just want execute application (didReceiveRemoteNotification) bypassing "completionHandler()". 
I hope I have explained. Thanks.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification Does not get called when user taps on notification, check the documentation.